# If we mix alcohol and water, then we heat them, will the temperature stop at 78 degree which is boiling point of alcohol?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, physical-chemistry

I understand that if we heat alcohol only, the temperature will stop at its boiling point, which is 78 degree. Then the boiling point of water is 100 degree. What will happen to the boiling point if we mix alcohol and water in ratio of 1:1? Will the mixture stop at boiling point of alcohol or exceed it?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question? We can migrate it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The diagram above shows the observed vapor-liquid equilibrium behavior of ethanol-water mixtures at one atmosphere.  In the diagram, the curve to the left is the mole fraction of ethanol in the liquid and the curve to the right is the mole fraction in the vapor.  For a 1:1 molar mixture in the liquid, it shows that the bubble point is 353 K (80 C) rather than 78 C.  For a 1:1 mass mixture, the mole fraction ethanol in the liquid is 0.28 and the bubble point is 82 C.